# How to prove that the scattering amlitude of bi-adjoint scalar field theory admits a Cachazo-He-Yuan (CHY) representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, amplituhedron

How to prove that the scattering amlitude of bi-adjoint scalar field theory admits a Cachazo-He-Yuan (CHY) representation?

Comment: Have you tried reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0885 ?